# how to add class after list-group-item in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">&nbsp;</span><a href="beauty-parlour-dharapuram.html">Beauty Parlour</a><span class="badge">24</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span><a href="sticker-arts-dharapuram.html">Sticker Arts</a><span class="badge">15</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery">&nbsp;</span><a href="hotel-dharapuram.html">Hotels</a><span class="badge">40</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add my own class after list-group-item, I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

How you need to do it? With script? For example, jQuery snippet for you:

```
$('.list-group-item').addClass('your-class-here');
```

As result -

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item your-class-here"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">&nbsp;</span><a href="beauty-parlour-dharapuram.html">Beauty Parlour</a><span class="badge">24</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item your-class-here"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span><a href="sticker-arts-dharapuram.html">Sticker Arts</a><span class="badge">15</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item your-class-here"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery">&nbsp;</span><a href="hotel-dharapuram.html">Hotels</a><span class="badge">40</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using javascript.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the problem. If you need just HTML - edit your code, add the class via whitespace in the attribute `class`, as in example above.

Comment: Yes, I also don't understand :D